# How to remove accents in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, diacritics

I've just compiled a database of 1 million place names. I'm going to use it in an auto-complete widget to look up cities. A lot of these places have accents... I want to be able to find records when a user types the name without an accent.

In order to do this, I've got a 2nd column with an unaccented copy of the name. Many of these records are still blank, so I want to write a query to fill them in. Is this possible in straight MySQL? If so, how?

Comment: look on this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302813/normalizing-accented-characters-in-mysql-queries,
you dont need to make another column, change the query

Comment: why not using regex instead e.g. (a|á)

Comment: @Eric Fortis regex is unecessary in this case, and heavy

Comment: @eric, because that would get huge. PHP's iconv() would help. I will note that within the TCPDF source, though, there's many special consideration handled that aren't native to whatever library PHP is using (in order to be very Unicode safe/aware).

Comment: @Eric Fortis: Given all the possible accent combinations, this is going to be a *long* regex, and it's likely that you'll forget some. Also, some characters don't convert quite logically into ASCII in some encodings (e.g. in German, `ö` could become `oe`)

Comment: @Haim: Did you read the first and only answer? It suggests adding another column.

Comment: @mark sorry is my mistake , i hope the link help

Comment: MySQL 8.0 added true [accent insensitive collations](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/new-collations-in-mysql-8-0-0/) so the accepted answer, using the appropriate collation, completely solves the problem. You can create indexes over generated columns too, which means you don't have to create a new column. The accent insensitive data will come from the index itself

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you set an appropriate collation for the column then the value within the field will compare equal to its unaccented equivalent naturally.

```
mysql> SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 'é' = 'e';
+------------+
| 'é' = 'e' |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

Comment: question.. how well would this work for very non-English characters?

Comment: @zanlok: Not so well. It does a few, such as "ß" being equal to "ss", but much further and it breaks down.

Comment: `"ß" = "ss" COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` -- is a match.  "Combining diacriticals also work in that collation.

Comment: `ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`

Comment: MySQL 8.0 introduced [accent insensitive](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/new-collations-in-mysql-8-0-0/) collations like `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` and language-specific collations like `utf8mb4_pl_0900_ai_ci` or `utf8mb4_de_pb_0900_ai_ci` which solve the problem.

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem, so I wrote a list of querys based on a PHP script I have to remove accents and make SEO friendly URLs:

Maybe you would like to add other special characters, such as the `$` or `£` symbols...

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Š','S');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'š','s');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Ð','Dj');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Ž','Z');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ž','z');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'À','A');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Á','A');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Â','A');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Ã','A');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Ä','A');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Å','A');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Æ','A');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Ç','C');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'È','E');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'É','E');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Ê','E');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Ë','E');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Ì','I');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Í','I');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Î','I');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Ï','I');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Ñ','N');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Ò','O');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Ó','O');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Ô','O');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Õ','O');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Ö','O');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Ø','O');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Ù','U');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Ú','U');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Û','U');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Ü','U');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Ý','Y');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Þ','B');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ß','Ss');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'à','a');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'á','a');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'â','a');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ã','a');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ä','a');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'å','a');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'æ','a');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ç','c');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'è','e');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'é','e');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ê','e');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ë','e');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ì','i');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'í','i');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'î','i');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ï','i');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ð','o');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ñ','n');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ò','o');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ó','o');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ô','o');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'õ','o');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ö','o');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ø','o');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ù','u');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ú','u');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'û','u');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ý','y');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ý','y');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'þ','b');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ÿ','y');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ƒ','f');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'.',' ');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,' ','-');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'--','-');

UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ě','e');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ž','z');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'š','s');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'č','c');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ř','r');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ď','d');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ť','t');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ň','n');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'ů','u');

UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Ě','E');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Ž','Z');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Š','S');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Č','C');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Ř','R');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Ď','D');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Ť','T');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Ň','N');
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'Ů','U');

UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN = LOWER(COLUMN);
```

Comment: congrats, great stored procedure

Comment: A) This actually answers the title question B) extremly useful when you have a large list of items with no slug/pretty-url pre-generated and you want to generate them directly in DB (because of the large amount of values) BTW: I would add `ě, ž, š, č , ř , ď, ť, ň, ů`

Comment: Works perfect! Regards.

Comment: It *does* remove the accents, however, some languages use different representations for some values (like in german 'ä' is 'ae', 'ö' is 'oe', ...).

Answer (score 16):

I share this maybe can help....:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `remove_accents`(`str` TEXT)
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    NO SQL
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
    COMMENT ''

BEGIN

    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Š','S');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'š','s');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ð','Dj');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ž','Z');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ž','z');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'À','A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Á','A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Â','A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ã','A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ä','A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Å','A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Æ','A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ç','C');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'È','E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'É','E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ê','E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ë','E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ì','I');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Í','I');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Î','I');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ï','I');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ñ','N');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ò','O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ó','O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ô','O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Õ','O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ö','O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ø','O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ù','U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ú','U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Û','U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ü','U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ý','Y');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Þ','B');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ß','Ss');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'à','a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'á','a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'â','a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ã','a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ä','a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'å','a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'æ','a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ç','c');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'è','e');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'é','e');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ê','e');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ë','e');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ì','i');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'í','i');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'î','i');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ï','i');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ð','o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ñ','n');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ò','o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ó','o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ô','o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'õ','o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ö','o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ø','o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ù','u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ú','u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'û','u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ý','y');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ý','y');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'þ','b');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ÿ','y');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ƒ','f');


    RETURN str;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 14):

```
drop function if exists fn_remove_accents;
delimiter |
create function fn_remove_accents( textvalue varchar(20000) )
returns varchar(20000)
begin

set @textvalue = textvalue;

-- ACCENTS
set @withaccents = 'ŠšŽžÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝŸÞàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöøùúûüýÿþƒ';
set @withoutaccents = 'SsZzAAAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOOUUUUYYBaaaaaaaceeeeiiiinoooooouuuuyybf';
set @count = length(@withaccents);

while @count > 0 do
    set @textvalue = replace(@textvalue, substring(@withaccents, @count, 1), substring(@withoutaccents, @count, 1));
    set @count = @count - 1;
end while;

-- SPECIAL CHARS
set @special = '!@#$%¨&*()_+=§¹²³£¢¬"`´{[^~}]<,>.:;?/°ºª+*|\\''';
set @count = length(@special);
while @count > 0 do
    set @textvalue = replace(@textvalue, substring(@special, @count, 1), '');
    set @count = @count - 1;
end while;

return @textvalue;

end
|
```

Comment: The solution is great but uses session variables instead of local variables and is missing the DETERMINISTIC keyword. Please see updated solution below...

Answer (score 4):

Here is an easy solution with a single query :

```
UPDATE `my_table` SET alias = lower(name),
alias = replace(alias,'Š','S'),
alias = replace(alias,'š','s'),
alias = replace(alias,'Ð','Dj'),
alias = replace(alias,'Ž','Z'),
alias = replace(alias,'ž','z'),
alias = replace(alias,'À','A'),
alias = replace(alias,'Á','A'),
alias = replace(alias,'Â','A'),
alias = replace(alias,'Ã','A'),
alias = replace(alias,'Ä','A'),
alias = replace(alias,'Å','A'),
alias = replace(alias,'Æ','A'),
alias = replace(alias,'Ç','C'),
alias = replace(alias,'È','E'),
alias = replace(alias,'É','E'),
alias = replace(alias,'Ê','E'),
alias = replace(alias,'Ë','E'),
alias = replace(alias,'Ì','I'),
alias = replace(alias,'Í','I'),
alias = replace(alias,'Î','I'),
alias = replace(alias,'Ï','I'),
alias = replace(alias,'Ñ','N'),
alias = replace(alias,'Ò','O'),
alias = replace(alias,'Ó','O'),
alias = replace(alias,'Ô','O'),
alias = replace(alias,'Õ','O'),
alias = replace(alias,'Ö','O'),
alias = replace(alias,'Ø','O'),
alias = replace(alias,'Ù','U'),
alias = replace(alias,'Ú','U'),
alias = replace(alias,'Û','U'),
alias = replace(alias,'Ü','U'),
alias = replace(alias,'Ý','Y'),  
alias = replace(alias,'š','s'),
alias = replace(alias,'Ð','Dj')
alias = replace(alias,'ž','z'),
alias = replace(alias,'Þ','B'),
alias = replace(alias,'ß','Ss'),
alias = replace(alias,'à','a'),
alias = replace(alias,'á','a'),
alias = replace(alias,'â','a'),
alias = replace(alias,'ã','a'),
alias = replace(alias,'ä','a'),
alias = replace(alias,'å','a'),
alias = replace(alias,'æ','a'),
alias = replace(alias,'ç','c'),
alias = replace(alias,'è','e'),
alias = replace(alias,'é','e'),
alias = replace(alias,'ê','e'),
alias = replace(alias,'ë','e'),
alias = replace(alias,'ì','i'),
alias = replace(alias,'í','i'),
alias = replace(alias,'î','i'),
alias = replace(alias,'ï','i'),
alias = replace(alias,'ð','o'),
alias = replace(alias,'ñ','n'),
alias = replace(alias,'ò','o'),
alias = replace(alias,'ó','o'),
alias = replace(alias,'ô','o'),
alias = replace(alias,'õ','o'),
alias = replace(alias,'ö','o'),
alias = replace(alias,'ø','o'),
alias = replace(alias,'ù','u'),
alias = replace(alias,'ú','u'),
alias = replace(alias,'û','u'),
alias = replace(alias,'ý','y'),
alias = replace(alias,'ý','y'),
alias = replace(alias,'þ','b'),
alias = replace(alias,'ÿ','y'),
alias = replace(alias,'ƒ','f'),
alias = replace(alias, 'œ', 'oe'),
alias = trim(alias);
```

In this  example :

- 'my_table' is the name of the table,
- 'name' is the original field
- 'alias' is the new field

Hope it helps !

You can also check this variant if you try to generate a slug field with mysql :
[Easy way of generating a slug name column from the name column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065288/easy-way-of-generating-a-slug-name-column-from-the-name-column/#31244866)

Comment: This is great! Just quick comments: you're missing a comma after the line "alias = replace(alias,'Ð','Dj')".

And you can also add these two extra lines, to catch a few more variations:
alias = replace(alias, 'Ł', 'L'),
alias = replace(alias, 'ą', 'a'),

Answer (score 2):

The solution of user3245067 is great, but it uses session variables.
This is the solution with local variables and also with DETERMINISTIC keyword for mysql 5.5. Tested with german umlaute in mysql-5.5.

```
drop function if exists fn_remove_accents;
delimiter $$
create function fn_remove_accents( param_textvalue varchar(20000) )
returns varchar(20000) DETERMINISTIC
begin

DECLARE var_textvalue VARCHAR(20000);
DECLARE var_withaccents VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE var_withoutaccents VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE var_count INT;
DECLARE var_special INT;

set var_textvalue = param_textvalue;

-- ACCENTS
set var_withaccents = 'ŠšŽžÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝŸÞàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöøùúûüýÿþƒ';
set var_withoutaccents = 'SsZzAAAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOOUUUUYYBaaaaaaaceeeeiiiinoooooouuuuyybf';
set var_count = length(var_withaccents);

while var_count > 0 do
    set var_textvalue = replace(var_textvalue, substring(var_withaccents, var_count, 1), substring(var_withoutaccents, var_count, 1));
    set var_count = var_count - 1;
end while;

-- SPECIAL CHARS
set var_special = '!var_#$%¨&*()_+=§¹²³£¢¬"`´{[^~}]<,>.:;?/°ºª+*|\\''';
set var_count = length(var_special);
while var_count > 0 do
    set var_textvalue = replace(var_textvalue, substring(var_special, var_count, 1), '');
    set var_count = var_count - 1;
end while;

return var_textvalue;

end$$

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Hi! Are you sure of your var_special ? Why do you have this pattern : var_ ?

Comment: I use the pattern "var_" to easily distinguish variables and column names - this is especially useful if using selects in the function, but admittedly it's not that valuable in here :).

Comment: I second Laurent.B 's comment. Probably there is misunderstanding, we are puzzled by the content of the var_special , not by its name. Also, I think it should be a string instead of INT .

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if MariaDB's `REGEXP_REPLACE(col, 'e', 'e')` with utf8_unicode_ci would do all the `e`s at once.

Comment: `REGEX` functions normally treats accented characters as unequal with the normal characters. So this will not work

Comment: Yes, MySQL 8.0 should work. It is not the case in `MariaDB` yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an accent removal function based on WordPress's [remove_accents()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_accents/).

The only differences are:

- Changing "ß" to "ss".
- Removing the more complicated replacement logic. Only the `$chars` array was ported over.

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `remove_accents`(`str` TEXT)
    RETURNS TEXT
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ª', 'a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'º', 'o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'À', 'A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Á', 'A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Â', 'A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ã', 'A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ä', 'A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Å', 'A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Æ', 'AE');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ç', 'C');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'È', 'E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'É', 'E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ê', 'E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ë', 'E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ì', 'I');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Í', 'I');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Î', 'I');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ï', 'I');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ð', 'D');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ñ', 'N');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ò', 'O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ó', 'O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ô', 'O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Õ', 'O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ö', 'O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ù', 'U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ú', 'U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Û', 'U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ü', 'U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ý', 'Y');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Þ', 'TH');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ß', 'ss');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'à', 'a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'á', 'a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'â', 'a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ã', 'a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ä', 'a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'å', 'a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'æ', 'ae');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ç', 'c');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'è', 'e');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'é', 'e');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ê', 'e');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ë', 'e');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ì', 'i');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'í', 'i');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'î', 'i');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ï', 'i');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ð', 'd');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ñ', 'n');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ò', 'o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ó', 'o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ô', 'o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'õ', 'o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ö', 'o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ø', 'o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ù', 'u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ú', 'u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'û', 'u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ü', 'u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ý', 'y');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'þ', 'th');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ÿ', 'y');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ø', 'O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ā', 'A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ā', 'a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ă', 'A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ă', 'a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ą', 'A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ą', 'a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ć', 'C');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ć', 'c');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ĉ', 'C');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ĉ', 'c');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ċ', 'C');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ċ', 'c');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Č', 'C');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'č', 'c');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ď', 'D');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ď', 'd');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Đ', 'D');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'đ', 'd');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ē', 'E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ē', 'e');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ĕ', 'E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ĕ', 'e');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ė', 'E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ė', 'e');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ę', 'E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ę', 'e');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ě', 'E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ě', 'e');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ĝ', 'G');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ĝ', 'g');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ğ', 'G');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ğ', 'g');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ġ', 'G');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ġ', 'g');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ģ', 'G');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ģ', 'g');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ĥ', 'H');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ĥ', 'h');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ħ', 'H');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ħ', 'h');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ĩ', 'I');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ĩ', 'i');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ī', 'I');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ī', 'i');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ĭ', 'I');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ĭ', 'i');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Į', 'I');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'į', 'i');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'İ', 'I');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ı', 'i');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ĳ', 'IJ');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ĳ', 'ij');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ĵ', 'J');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ĵ', 'j');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ķ', 'K');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ķ', 'k');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ĸ', 'k');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ĺ', 'L');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ĺ', 'l');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ļ', 'L');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ļ', 'l');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ľ', 'L');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ľ', 'l');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ŀ', 'L');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ŀ', 'l');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ł', 'L');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ł', 'l');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ń', 'N');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ń', 'n');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ņ', 'N');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ņ', 'n');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ň', 'N');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ň', 'n');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ŉ', 'n');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ŋ', 'N');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ŋ', 'n');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ō', 'O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ō', 'o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ŏ', 'O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ŏ', 'o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ő', 'O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ő', 'o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Œ', 'OE');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'œ', 'oe');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ŕ', 'R');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ŕ', 'r');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ŗ', 'R');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ŗ', 'r');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ř', 'R');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ř', 'r');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ś', 'S');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ś', 's');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ŝ', 'S');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ŝ', 's');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ş', 'S');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ş', 's');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Š', 'S');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'š', 's');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ţ', 'T');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ţ', 't');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ť', 'T');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ť', 't');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ŧ', 'T');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ŧ', 't');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ũ', 'U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ũ', 'u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ū', 'U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ū', 'u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ŭ', 'U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ŭ', 'u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ů', 'U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ů', 'u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ű', 'U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ű', 'u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ų', 'U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ų', 'u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ŵ', 'W');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ŵ', 'w');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ŷ', 'Y');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ŷ', 'y');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ÿ', 'Y');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ź', 'Z');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ź', 'z');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ż', 'Z');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ż', 'z');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ž', 'Z');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ž', 'z');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ſ', 's');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ə', 'E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ǝ', 'e');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ș', 'S');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ș', 's');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ț', 'T');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ț', 't');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, '€', 'E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, '£', '');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ơ', 'O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ơ', 'o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ư', 'U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ư', 'u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ầ', 'A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ầ', 'a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ằ', 'A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ằ', 'a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ề', 'E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ề', 'e');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ồ', 'O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ồ', 'o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ờ', 'O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ờ', 'o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ừ', 'U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ừ', 'u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ỳ', 'Y');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ỳ', 'y');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ả', 'A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ả', 'a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ẩ', 'A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ẩ', 'a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ẳ', 'A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ẳ', 'a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ẻ', 'E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ẻ', 'e');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ể', 'E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ể', 'e');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ỉ', 'I');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ỉ', 'i');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ỏ', 'O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ỏ', 'o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ổ', 'O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ổ', 'o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ở', 'O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ở', 'o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ủ', 'U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ủ', 'u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ử', 'U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ử', 'u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ỷ', 'Y');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ỷ', 'y');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ẫ', 'A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ẫ', 'a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ẵ', 'A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ẵ', 'a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ẽ', 'E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ẽ', 'e');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ễ', 'E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ễ', 'e');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ỗ', 'O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ỗ', 'o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ỡ', 'O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ỡ', 'o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ữ', 'U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ữ', 'u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ỹ', 'Y');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ỹ', 'y');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ấ', 'A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ấ', 'a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ắ', 'A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ắ', 'a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ế', 'E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ế', 'e');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ố', 'O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ố', 'o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ớ', 'O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ớ', 'o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ứ', 'U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ứ', 'u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ạ', 'A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ạ', 'a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ậ', 'A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ậ', 'a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ặ', 'A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ặ', 'a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ẹ', 'E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ẹ', 'e');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ệ', 'E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ệ', 'e');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ị', 'I');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ị', 'i');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ọ', 'O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ọ', 'o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ộ', 'O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ộ', 'o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ợ', 'O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ợ', 'o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ụ', 'U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ụ', 'u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ự', 'U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ự', 'u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ỵ', 'Y');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ỵ', 'y');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ɑ', 'a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ǖ', 'U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ǖ', 'u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ǘ', 'U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ǘ', 'u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ǎ', 'A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ǎ', 'a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ǐ', 'I');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ǐ', 'i');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ǒ', 'O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ǒ', 'o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ǔ', 'U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ǔ', 'u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ǚ', 'U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ǚ', 'u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'Ǜ', 'U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, 'ǜ', 'u');

    RETURN str;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This is as bad and slow as all other replacement answers. The accepted answer shows how to solve this in the easiest and fastest way by using the appropriate collation. [MySQL 8.0 added accent-insensitive collations](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/new-collations-in-mysql-8-0-0/) which means no replacements are needed to allow indexed searches

Comment: BTW the replacements are not even wrong. Whoever wrote them had absolutely no idea what they were doing. The Greek unaccented letter `η` is most definitely not the accented form of the English `i`. Or is it the Turkish `i`?

Comment: And every German will tell you that `ß` is the equivalent of `ss`, not  `s`. This replacement list is 70-80% wrong, just due to the Greek characters

Comment: Yes, you're completely right. It's such a no-good, very bad, poopy, naïve answer. But please enlighten me: how would you generate and store a slug in MySQL 8 without accents using an accent-insensitive collation? The collation doesn't actually return a string with no accents. What statement or function can I use to remove accents then? Let's see your solution.

Comment: None at all because it's not needed. The accepted answer already shows what to do. A collation doesn't return anything, it's the ordering and comparison rules used during searching or indexing. Any indexes created over that column will use accent insensitive comparison and ordering. As the accepted answer shows, `SELECT 'é' = 'e'` returns `1` because the two values are equal. Not some function output, the values themselves are equal

Comment: It is needed. If I have a database (which I do) of US territories and cities/towns/villages, and I use the `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` collation, and one village is called "Aūa" in American Samoa, and I generate and store the slug using the accented village name, it will come out something like, "aūa-american-samoa". This value will be returned to my application which generates links and handles routing and I don't want accented characters in my URLs for a number of reasons. Using an accent-insensitive collation does not solve my problem.

Comment: That's completely different from what the question asks or what collations do. The question isn't about slugs at all. Accent insensitive search means that searching for `Aua` should match `Aūa`

Comment: The title of the question is, "How to remove accents in MySQL?". I Googled "mysql remove accents" verbatim, this question was the first result on page one, and that's how I got here. All the solutions here didn't work for me so I made my own and posted it. If every answer had to narrowly answer the question down to the letter, Stack Overflow wouldn't be as useful. This question is now almost 13 years old and has 70k views. At this point, it shouldn't be just about answering OP's specific problem but providing solutions to people like me who got here through SEO from the title of the question.

Comment: Even for that, the answer you posted is **VERY** bad because it completely mangles over 70% of replacements. It will prevent valid matches while matching unrelated strings.

Comment: I did read the question. But what's even the point of posting on Stack Overflow? Isn't it supposed to be about sharing knowledge and helping other people? The last time OP posted anything here was 2011. He probably solved his problem a long time ago and doesn't need any more solutions. People coming here might have a search problem like OP but maybe they also might just want a function to remove accents. Why is it so bad to have both types of answers? Both are on-topic, either through the title or body of the question.

Comment: This isn't about sharing knowledge or having both types of answers. It's about posting a bad answer and insisting on it. There's *no* way you can argue that `ß` is equivalent to `s`, or that `ᾗ` is equivalent to `i`. That's no different than arguing that the English `i` is equivalent to `y`.

Comment: If the source of the replacements is bad, I'll take the criticism. I'm not a language expert. If you can suggest a better source, I'll update my function. My goal is just to create a function which creates decent-looking slugs for URLs without accents. Accuracy is important, don't get me wrong, but it's not the only consideration.

Comment: I've updated the replacement source to one from a WordPress function. If WordPress got it wrong, it's beyond me to fix it. I just want good-enough-looking URLs.

Answer (score -1):

This is the fastest and most efficient way I found:

```
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Š','S');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'š','s');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Ð','Dj');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Ž','Z');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'ž','z');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'À','A');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Á','A');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Â','A');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Ã','A');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Ä','A');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Å','A');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Æ','A');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Ç','C');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'È','E');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'É','E');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Ê','E');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Ë','E');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Ì','I');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Í','I');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Î','I');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Ï','I');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Ñ','N');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Ò','O');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Ó','O');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Ô','O');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Õ','O');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Ö','O');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Ø','O');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Ù','U');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Ú','U');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Û','U');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Ü','U');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Ý','Y');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'Þ','B');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'ß','Ss');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'à','a');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'á','a');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'â','a');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'ã','a');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'ä','a');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'å','a');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'æ','a');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'ç','c');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'è','e');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'é','e');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'ê','e');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'ë','e');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'ì','i');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'í','i');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'î','i');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'ï','i');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'ð','o');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'ñ','n');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'ò','o');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'ó','o');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'ô','o');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'õ','o');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'ö','o');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'ø','o');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'ù','u');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'ú','u');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'û','u');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'ý','y');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'ý','y');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'þ','b');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'ÿ','y');
UPDATE movies SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'ƒ','f');
```

Comment: The fastest and most efficient way in MySQL 8.0+ is to use an accent-insensitive collation like `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`. These limited replacements won't even cover Eastern Europe

Answer (score -4):

Check out the MySQL manual on `CONVERT()` and `CAST()`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html

> CONVERT() provides a way to convert data between different character sets. The syntax is:
>
> `CONVERT(expr USING transcoding_name)`

Comment: CONVERT and CAST don't translit characters