# Using ICONV on mysql select - transform all characters to standard ascii

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, ascii, iconv, transliteration

I want to search in my database for polish cities which commonly consist of a lot of special characters. I want to migrate those to ASCII, so that even those without a polish keyboard can do a regular search.

In PHP it looks like

```
$ascii = iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $text);
```

but how to implement that in mysql select query?

```
select * from city where CONVERT(city using ASCII)=CONVERT(? using ASCII)
```

does not work, because it replaces all unknown characters with a question mark

```
select CONVERT('Lódź' using ascii );
-- RESULT: L?d?
```

Comment: besides such conversions are guess works, provide end-users a virtual keyboard?

Comment: mh sure, but this search is on the API side and it will be used by mobile applications. Beside it is more or less considered user friendly to allow both characters

Comment: sure I could use str_replace https://gist.github.com/mlaug/030889328263b5144b72 but maybe there is a more readable and more confident way

Comment: what charset and collation are you using to store the cities names?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4813651/1507998), if you use the collation `utf8_general_ci`, string comparations will be case and accent insensitive, so you won't need to specify any conversions when doing the query:

```
CREATE TABLE test (name varchar(100)) COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
INSERT test (name) VALUES ('Lódź');

SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = 'Lodz';

name
----
Lódź
```

[Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d37af/4)

And if you want to specify another collation for your column, you can even apply this collation in a specific query:

```
CREATE TABLE test (name varchar(100)) COLLATE 'utf8_polish_ci';
INSERT test (name) VALUES ('Lódź');


SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = 'Lodz';

Empty set (0.00 sec)


SELECT * FROM test WHERE name COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' = 'Lodz';

name
----
Lódź
```

[Second fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69dd64/5)

Answer (score 1):

### Operator Behaviors

#### Equal Operator `=`

If you are doing an exact searches using the [equal operator `=`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal) the solution from `@rsanchez` is correct. For instance, finding **row equal to `œ`** can be done using this exact value `œ` or its transliterated value `oe`:

```sql
SELECT 'œ' = 'oe' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ;
-- true
+-------------------------------------+
| 'œ' = 'oe' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci  |
+-------------------------------------+
|                                   1 |
+-------------------------------------+
```

Will return rows being **equal to `œ` or `oe`** if user use any of them.

#### `LIKE` Operator

However if you want to do fuzzy search using the [`LIKE` operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like), this won't work. For instance, searching for words containing `œ` by **typing `oe`** will not return row with `œ`.

```sql
SELECT 'œ' LIKE 'oe' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ;
-- false
+----------------------------------------+
| 'œ' LIKE 'oe' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci  |
+----------------------------------------+
|                                      0 |
+----------------------------------------+
```

#### Explanation ?

This is not a bug but the [expected behavior by SQL standard (see Alexander Barkov answer)](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14716) as `LIKE` is doing comparison on a character basis while `=` use a more complex approach (e.g. allowing transliteration equality).

### Solutions

#### Provide the transliterated form

A solution would be to generate the transliteration of your search and modify your query to search for each form:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `mytable` 
  WHERE `myfield` LIKE 'oe' or `myfield` LIKE 'oe' 
COLLATE  utf8_unicode_ci;
```

#### Use FullText search

Since [MySQL 5.6, fulltext search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-nutshell.html) is **now available for InnoDB** (previously it was only available for `MyISAM` tables).

Answer (score 0):

its late but my answer is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TO_ASCII(
    text_to_replace MEDIUMTEXT
) RETURNS MEDIUMTEXT
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE char_from, char_to VARCHAR(50);

    SET char_from := 'ĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŻŹąćęłńóśżź ';
    SET char_to   := 'ASCZZEOLNasczzeoln_';
    SET i := CHAR_LENGTH(char_from);

    WHILE i
        DO
            SET text_to_replace := REPLACE(text_to_replace, SUBSTR(char_from, i, 1), SUBSTR(char_to, i, 1));
            SET i:= i - 1;
        END WHILE;

    RETURN text_to_replace;
END;
```

and usage:

```
SELECT TO_ASCII('abcąśćó   ĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŻŹąćęłńóśżź  ĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŻŹąćęłńóśżź ');
```