# Easy way of generating a slug name column from the name column?

Tags: mysql, sql

`db_products` table:

```
| ID | Name         |
| 40 | Foo Bar!~~~~ |
```

I want to generate a slug name column:

```
| ID | Name         | Slug_Name |
| 40 | Foo Bar!~~~~ | foo-bar   |
```

Can this be actually done via SQL? Or would I need to write a script using a different language?

EDIT: I'm generating slugs in PHP using this function:

```
function toSlug($string,$space="-") {
    if (function_exists('iconv')) {
        $string = @iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string);
    }
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/", "", $string);
    $string = strtolower($string);
    $string = str_replace(" ", $space, $string);
    return $string;
}
```

So far my SQL skills fairly basic.

`ALTER TABLE db_products ADD Slug_Name VARCHAR`

How do I loop through each row and set `Slug_Name = toSlug(Name)` but in SQL?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  MySQL has several string manipulation functions. You may want to look at replace(), lower(), trim() and regexp() specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly do a string replace using MySQL. The [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) lists quite a few string functions you might find useful.

```
SELECT REPLACE('Foo Bar!~~~~', '~', '');
SELECT LOWER('Foo Bar!');
```

I also ran across this [blog post](http://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql/) on using regular expressions in MySQL.

Updated: Details from the blog post I mentioned:

So what I would recommend is creating a function for doing a regular expression replace:

```
DELIMITER $$
FUNCTION `regex_replace`(pattern varchar(1000),replacement varchar(1000),original varchar(1000))
RETURNS varchar(1000)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE temp VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE ch VARCHAR(1);
DECLARE i INT;
SET i = 1;
SET temp = original;
IF original REGEXP pattern THEN
    SET temp = "";
    loop_label: LOOP
    IF i>CHAR_LENGTH(original) THEN
        LEAVE loop_label;
    END IF;
    SET ch = SUBSTRING(original,i,1);
    IF NOT ch REGEXP pattern THEN
        SET temp = CONCAT(temp,ch);
    ELSE
        SET temp = CONCAT(temp,replacement);
    END IF;
    SET i=i+1;
END LOOP;
END IF;
RETURN temp;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then something akin to the following

```
SELECT regex_replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '', '%$&?/’|test><+-,][)(' )
```

If you're not comfortable with that approach, you can always just run some update calls using replace

```
update db_products set Slug_Name = replace(Name, '~', '');
```

Comment: Combined with `TRIGGER` this could be very effective. Never used one, but seems like it should be something like `CREATE TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT FOR EACH ROW SET new.slug = COOL_REPLACE_FUNCTION(new.title);`

Comment: So, help me understand what you're asking for. You have what looks like a perfectly good solution in PHP. You're wanting to update rows already in your database?

Comment: No, create a new column that contains slug names for each respective row.

Answer (score 11):

Here is an easy solution with a single query :

```
UPDATE `my_table` SET alias = lower(name),
alias = replace(alias, '.', ' '),
alias = replace(alias, '\'', '-'),
alias = replace(alias,'š','s'),
alias = replace(alias,'Ð','Dj'),
alias = replace(alias,'ž','z'),
alias = replace(alias,'Þ','B'),
alias = replace(alias,'ß','Ss'),
alias = replace(alias,'à','a'),
alias = replace(alias,'á','a'),
alias = replace(alias,'â','a'),
alias = replace(alias,'ã','a'),
alias = replace(alias,'ä','a'),
alias = replace(alias,'å','a'),
alias = replace(alias,'æ','a'),
alias = replace(alias,'ç','c'),
alias = replace(alias,'è','e'),
alias = replace(alias,'é','e'),
alias = replace(alias,'ê','e'),
alias = replace(alias,'ë','e'),
alias = replace(alias,'ì','i'),
alias = replace(alias,'í','i'),
alias = replace(alias,'î','i'),
alias = replace(alias,'ï','i'),
alias = replace(alias,'ð','o'),
alias = replace(alias,'ñ','n'),
alias = replace(alias,'ò','o'),
alias = replace(alias,'ó','o'),
alias = replace(alias,'ô','o'),
alias = replace(alias,'õ','o'),
alias = replace(alias,'ö','o'),
alias = replace(alias,'ø','o'),
alias = replace(alias,'ù','u'),
alias = replace(alias,'ú','u'),
alias = replace(alias,'û','u'),
alias = replace(alias,'ý','y'),
alias = replace(alias,'ý','y'),
alias = replace(alias,'þ','b'),
alias = replace(alias,'ÿ','y'),
alias = replace(alias,'ƒ','f'),
alias = replace(alias, 'œ', 'oe'),
alias = replace(alias, '€', 'euro'),
alias = replace(alias, '$', 'dollars'),
alias = replace(alias, '£', ''),
alias = trim(alias),
alias = replace(alias, ' ', '-'),
alias = replace(alias, '--', '-') ;
```

In this  example :

- 'my_table' is the name of the table,
- 'name' is the original field
- 'alias' is the name of my slug field

Hope it helps !

Comment: Error on line 5, you are missing a comma at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Change your **tbl_name** and **field_name** and **slug**_field_name

```
SELECT field_name,
 REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
 REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
 REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
 LOWER(TRIM(field_name)), ':', ''), ')', ''), '(', ''), ',', ''), '\\', ''), '\/', ''), '\"', ''), '?', ''), '\'', ''), '&', ''), '!', ''), '.', ''), ' ', '-'), '--', '-'), '--', '-')
AS `slug_field_name`
FROM tbl_name
```

For test '**Your String**' result **your-string**:

```
SELECT
 REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
 REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
 REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
 LOWER(TRIM('Your String')), ':', ''), ')', ''), '(', ''), ',', ''), '\\', ''), '\/', ''), '\"', ''), '?', ''), '\'', ''), '&', ''), '!', ''), '.', ''), ' ', '-'), '--', '-'), '--', '-')
AS `slug_test`
```

*For special characters*:

Append a **[REPLACE(]** and a **[, ':', '')]**

For example **ö** character in this string "**Hallo schöne Welt**"

Result is "**hallo-schone-welt**"

```
SELECT
 REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
 REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
 REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
 REPLACE(
 LOWER(TRIM('Hallo schöne Welt')), 'ö', 'o'), ':', ''), ')', ''), '(', ''), ',', ''), '\\', ''), '\/', ''), '\"', ''), '?', ''), '\'', ''), '&', ''), '!', ''), '.', ''), ' ', '-'), '--', '-'), '--', '-')
AS `slug_test`
```

Answer (score 1):

I made some edits to Erwan Dupeux-Maire's answer, to account for some missing characters, which I had in my `name` field: ',', '&', and '/'

```
UPDATE `table` SET slug = lower(name),
slug = replace(slug, '.', ''),
slug = replace(slug, '\'', '-'),
slug = replace(slug, '/', '-'),
slug = replace(slug,'š','s'),
slug = replace(slug,'Ð','Dj'),
slug = replace(slug,'ž','z'),
slug = replace(slug,'Þ','B'),
slug = replace(slug,'ß','Ss'),
slug = replace(slug,'à','a'),
slug = replace(slug,'á','a'),
slug = replace(slug,'â','a'),
slug = replace(slug,'ã','a'),
slug = replace(slug,'ä','a'),
slug = replace(slug,'å','a'),
slug = replace(slug,'æ','a'),
slug = replace(slug,'ç','c'),
slug = replace(slug,'è','e'),
slug = replace(slug,'é','e'),
slug = replace(slug,'ê','e'),
slug = replace(slug,'ë','e'),
slug = replace(slug,'ì','i'),
slug = replace(slug,'í','i'),
slug = replace(slug,'î','i'),
slug = replace(slug,'ï','i'),
slug = replace(slug,'ð','o'),
slug = replace(slug,'ñ','n'),
slug = replace(slug,'ò','o'),
slug = replace(slug,'ó','o'),
slug = replace(slug,'ô','o'),
slug = replace(slug,'õ','o'),
slug = replace(slug,'ö','o'),
slug = replace(slug,'ø','o'),
slug = replace(slug,'ù','u'),
slug = replace(slug,'ú','u'),
slug = replace(slug,'û','u'),
slug = replace(slug,'ý','y'),
slug = replace(slug,'ý','y'),
slug = replace(slug,'þ','b'),
slug = replace(slug,'ÿ','y'),
slug = replace(slug,'ƒ','f'),
slug = replace(slug, 'œ', 'oe'),
slug = replace(slug, '€', 'euro'),
slug = replace(slug, '$', 'dollars'),
slug = replace(slug, '£', ''),
slug = trim(slug),
slug = replace(slug, ',', ''),
slug = replace(slug, '&', ''),
slug = replace(slug, ' ', '-'),
slug = replace(slug, '--', '-');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple and fast way to generate **slug** from **name** field:

```
UPDATE store_book SET
    slug = lower(title),
    slug = replace(slug, '.', ' '),
    slug = replace(slug, ',', ' '),
    slug = replace(slug, ';', ' '),
    slug = replace(slug, ':', ' '),
    slug = replace(slug, '?', ' '),
    slug = replace(slug, '%', ' '),
    slug = replace(slug, '$', ' '),
    slug = replace(slug, '&', ' '),
    slug = replace(slug, '#', ' '),
    slug = replace(slug, '*', ' '),
    slug = replace(slug, '!', ' '),
    slug = replace(slug, '_', ' '),
    slug = replace(slug, '@', ' '),
    slug = replace(slug, '+', ' '),
    slug = replace(slug, '(', ' '),
    slug = replace(slug, ')', ' '),
    slug = replace(slug, '[', ' '),
    slug = replace(slug, ']', ' '),
    slug = replace(slug, '/', ' '),
    slug = replace(slug, '-', ' '),
    slug = replace(slug, '\'', ''),
    slug = trim(slug),
    slug = replace(slug, ' ', '-'),
    slug = replace(slug, '--', '-'),
    slug=replace(slug, 'ä', 'a'),
    slug=replace(slug, 'å', 'a'),
    slug=replace(slug, 'æ', 'a'),
    slug=replace(slug, 'ç', 'c'),
    slug=replace(slug, 'è', 'e'),
    slug=replace(slug, 'é', 'e'),
    slug=replace(slug, 'ê', 'e'),
    slug=replace(slug, 'ë', 'e'),
    slug=replace(slug, 'ì', 'i'),
    slug=replace(slug, 'í', 'i'),
    slug=replace(slug, 'î', 'i'),
    slug=replace(slug, 'ï', 'i'),
    slug=replace(slug, 'ð', 'o'),
    slug=replace(slug, 'ñ', 'n'),
    slug=replace(slug, 'ò', 'o'),
    slug=replace(slug, 'ó', 'o'),
    slug=replace(slug, 'ô', 'o'),
    slug=replace(slug, 'õ', 'o'),
    slug=replace(slug, 'ö', 'o'),
    slug=replace(slug, 'ø', 'o'),
    slug = replace(slug, 'ù','u'),
    slug = replace(slug, 'ú','u'),
    slug = replace(slug, 'û','u'),
    slug = replace(slug, 'ü','u'),
    slug = replace(slug, 'ý','y'),
    slug = replace(slug, 'ë','e'),
    slug = replace(slug, 'à','a'),
    slug = replace(slug, 'á','a'),
    slug = replace(slug, 'â','a'),
    slug = replace(slug, 'ã','a'),
    slug= replace(slug, '%', ''),
    slug= replace(slug, 'ç', 'c'),
    slug= replace(slug, 'ü', 'u'),
    slug= replace(slug, 'ğ', 'g'),
    slug= replace(slug, 'ş', 's'),
    slug= replace(slug, 'ß', 'b'),
    slug= replace(slug, 'ı', 'i'),
    slug= replace(slug, '.', ''),
    slug= replace(slug, 'ö', 'ö'),
    slug= replace(slug, 'ç', 'c'),
    slug= replace(slug, '#x27;', ''),
    slug = replace(slug, '--', '-');
```

at the end you can use below query to validate the **slug** field

```
SELECT * FROM store_book WHERE
    slug NOT RLIKE '^([a-z0-9]+\-)*[a-z0-9]+$';
```

Note your last statement should be

```
slug = replace(slug, '--', '-')
```

but you can add other characters before this line. To find what you need to add you can use above validation query if it returns any rows it means there is any character which is not supported in slug.