# Postgresql unaccent() equivalent in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

i have to compare two strings in a query like following:

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE column LIKE '%keyword%';
```

But i want to compare unaccented values of both `column` and `keyword`. Is there an unaccent() function or other way to achieve this in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, No there is no `unaccent()` function present in `MySQL`. To ignore the accent you will have to set the proper collation for the column you are trying to compare. Example: [How to remove accents in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813620/how-to-remove-accents-in-mysql)