# Transilerate accents in MySql like LIKE

Tags: mysql

I have a very long list of users. I want to group them by first letter of name. If the first letter is not a letter, it's grouped under `#`, so I have max 27 groups, for `a-z` + `#`.

I want to show only the gorup labels (e.g. `F`) if it will have results, and for every letter I want to know how many results it will have. So I do a single GROUP query to count all groups:

```
SELECT
  IF(lastname REGEXP '^[a-z]', UPPER(SUBSTRING(lastname, 1, 1)), '#') first_char,
  COUNT(1) num_users
GROUP BY first_char
```

That seems to work, BUT using REGEXP means that `Ö` isn't an `O`, but a `#`. That's a problem, because `LIKE` does find `'Ö' = 'O'`, so it will be in the `O` group when I `name LIKE 'O%'`. I could use REGEXP in the results query too, but I rather file `Ö` under `O`.

So the `LIKE` query works perfectly, but the GROUP query doesn't. How do I do **exactly** what `LIKE` does during comparisons?, so the group numbers and results always perfectly match.

Or another way to count correctly?

**edit 1**

Using `LIKE a OR LIKE b OR .. OR LIKE z` in the `IF` doesn't even work, because then the group might be `Ö` instead of `O`. The numbers will be correct, but the group label won't be. I really need a conversion...

**edit 2**

Thanks to @mpen. `lastname REGEXP '^[[:alpha:]]'` is shorter than 26 `LIKE`s, but the `Ö` label problem remains. Converting that outside MySQL is easy though.

Comment: Instead of `'^[a-z]'` can you try `[:alpha:]`? That should include accented characters I think, and then GROUP BY will *hopefully* group the same way that LIKE does (but I'm not sure). You may also need to `COLLATE` that first char into something like `utf8_unicode_ci` so it does the grouping properly.

Comment: That works!, BUT it's not perfect, see **edit 1**. Column is `utf8_unicode_ci` so no collate necessary. Grouping works.

Comment: You can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6945191/65387) but you're probably better off 'deburring' the letters in whatever scripting language you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the grouping like this:

```
select
    IF(name REGEXP '^[[:alpha:]]', UPPER(SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1)), '#') first_char,
    COUNT(1) num_users
from _grouptest
group by first_char
```

And then remove the accents in your scripting language of choice, or if you're brave, you can attempt to remove them in [pure MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4813620/65387).

- [_.deburr in JS](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#deburr)
- `Str::removeDiacritics` from my PHP lib [ptilz](https://packagist.org/packages/mnpenner/ptilz) which was yoinked from [WordPress](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L682)

Comment: `[:alpha:]` uses the same dark hardcoded conversion magic as `LIKE`. Why don't they expose that? =( I read somewhere how they do that, in greater detail than in [the LIKE docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like), but I can't find it anymore. I'm definitely not brave enough for manually transliterating.

Comment: @Rudie Yeah, I'm not sure why. Maybe partly because each codepoint is assigned a number or weight, rather than being translated back to an unaccented character. i.e., they don't actually have a table that does this mapping? At least I think that's how it works.

Comment: They have a table for mapping `O` and `Ö` to the same marker/number/weight, but not for mapping that marker to `O`. I guess that makes sense. `O` is not more correct or better than `Ö` so they wouldn't. But I would! `[:alpha:]` saves the day! Many thanks.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean. You said it better :-)