# How to search for character in sql that can not be entered by standard keyboard?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, utf-8

I am working on a Sanskrit MySql database that has special characters in the data like below: Mahāvākyavivaraṇa.

But user can only enter Mahavakyavivarana using a standard keyboard.

How may I perform a sql search with something like this:

```
SELECT manuscripts.* FROM manuscripts WHERE (Title = 'Mahavakyavivaraṇa')
```

and get output for

```
SELECT manuscripts.* FROM manuscripts WHERE (Title = 'Mahāvākyavivaraṇa')
```

I am using Ruby On Rails as programming language.

Answer (score 2):

> If you set an appropriate collation for the column then the value within the field will compare equal to its unaccented equivalent naturally.

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4813651/334314

Comment: How well do you think this is going to work for Sanskrit? My guess is not very and a transliteration library like stringex is probably a better bet.

Comment: @max - Generally it works with latin (A-Z) based characters.  If you have an example in Sanskrit, start a new Question and I will probably look into it.