# Matching db values with special chars

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to match values in query if the stored data has special characters, and the search query doesn't:

For example: I want to match a column with the following value:

```
Doña Ana
```

but I can only search using

```
Dona Ana
```

Comment: Here's a reasonable starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4813651/53341

Answer (score 0):

You may collate the column of interest to Latin general, which doesn't have accents:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE name COLLATE latin1_general_ci = 'Dona Ana';
```