# mysql regex utf-8 characters

Tags: mysql, regex, utf-8

I am trying to get data from `MySQL` database via `REGEX` with or without special utf-8 characters.

Let me explain on example :

If user enters word like `sirena` it should return rows which include words like `sirena`,`siréna`,`šíreňá` .. and so on..
also it should work backwards when he enters `siréná` it should return the same results..

I am trying to search it via `REGEX`, my query looks like this :

```
SELECT * FROM `content` WHERE `text` REGEXP '[sšŠ][iíÍ][rŕŔřŘ][eéÉěĚ][nňŇ][AaáÁäÄ0]'
```

It works only when in database is word `sirena` but not when there is word `siréňa`..

Is it because something with `UTF-8` and MySQL? (collation of mysql column is `utf8_general_ci`)

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL's regular expression library does not support utf-8.

See [Bug #30241 Regular expression problems](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30241), which has been open since 2007. They will have to change the regular expression library they use before that can be fixed, and I haven't found any announcement of when or if they will do this.

The only workaround I've seen is to search for specific HEX strings:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `content` WHERE HEX(`text`) REGEXP 'C3A9C588';
+----------+
| text     |
+----------+
| siréňa   |
+----------+
```

---

Re your comment:

No, I don't know of any solution with MySQL.

You might have to switch to PostgreSQL, because that RDBMS supports `\u` codes for UTF characters in their [regular expression syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html).

Comment: so there is no solution if my strings are variables?

Comment: Two years have passed since you answered this. Do you know of any updates about this topic?

Comment: @emisilva, click on the link I provided to check the status of that bug.

Comment: @emisilva If I remember right, my solution was to change collation on DB column to utf8_general_ci.. After thatm searching was working as expected... hope it helps

Comment: @emisilva check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647080/accent-insensitive-search-query-in-mysql

Comment: For me it didn't work when I did things like cami[óo]n, but it did work as expected with camión|camion

Comment: This worked perfectly!  I needed it to find corrupted, UTF-8 characters.  This worked: SELECT id, SomeField from SomeTable where HEX(SomeField) RLIKE 'C382' OR HEX(SomeField) RLIKE 'C383';

Answer (score 2):

Try something like ... `REGEXP '(a|b|[ab])'`

```
SELECT * FROM `content` WHERE `text` REGEXP '(s|š|Š|[sšŠ])(i|í|Í|[iíÍ])(r|ŕ|Ŕ|ř|Ř|[rŕŔřŘ])(e|é|É|ě|Ě|[eéÉěĚ])(n|ň|Ň|[nňŇ])(A|a|á|Á|ä|Ä|0|[AaáÁäÄ0])'
```

It works for me!

Answer (score -3):

Use the lib_mysqludf_preg library from the mysql UDF repository for PCRE regular expressions directly in mysql

Although MySQL's regular expression library does not support utf-8 the mysql UDF repository has the ability to use utf-8 compatible regex according PCRE regular expressions directly in mysql.

http://www.mysqludf.org/
https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg#readme

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Although MySQL's regular expression library does not support utf-8  the mysql UDF repository has the ability to use utf-8 compatible regex according PCRE regular expressions directly in mysql.

Comment: Wasted my time installing this library, turns out it does not support (meaning correctly handle) utf-8 at all. SELECT PREG_RLIKE('/aeiou/', 'àèìòù') returns 0, just like SELECT 'aeiou' RLIKE 'àèìòù' does. So, this library is no solution to the fact that MySQL does not handle utf8 correctly.

Comment: Confirming, lib_mysqludf_preg does not supports UTF8 (multi-byte character encoding) at all.