# mysql delete one cyrillic word select one cyrillic word

Tags: mysql, regex, utf-8, character-encoding, cyrillic

```
mysql>show full columns from  bpsw;
+--------+------------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field  | Type             | Collation | Null | Key | Default | Extra          | Privileges                      | Comment |
+--------+------------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| bpswid | int(10) unsigned | NULL      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | select,insert,update,references |         |
| badpsw | varchar(128)     | utf8_bin  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
+--------+------------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
```

dont say me about `not null` and `default null` :)

```
mysql> SELECT USER(), CHARSET(USER()), COLLATION(USER());
+----------------+-----------------+-------------------+
| USER()         | CHARSET(USER()) | COLLATION(USER()) |
+----------------+-----------------+-------------------+
| root@localhost | utf8            | utf8_general_ci   |
+----------------+-----------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

table contents:

```
mysql> select * from bpsw limit X offset XXX ;
+--------+------------------------+
| bpswid | badpsw                 |
+--------+------------------------+
| 495883 | by all manner of means |
| 495884 | by all means           |
| 495885 | by all odds            |
| 495886 | by an ace              |
| 495887 | by an iota             |
| 495888 | by and by              |
| 495889 | by and large           |
| 495890 | by any chance          |
| 495891 | by any manner of means |
| 495892 | by any means           |
+--------+------------------------+
...
|   94950 | яростных                                                    |
|    1599 | ярь-медянка                                                 |
|    1600 | ястреб-перепелятник                                         |
|    1601 | ястреб-тетеревятник                                         |
|   94999 | яфетический                                                 |
|    1603 | яхт-клуб                                                    |
|    1604 | яхт-клуба                                                   |
...
|    1938 | яванский желоб                                              |
|    1939 | яванское море                                               |
|   94690 | еще какое-то слово                                          |
|    1940 | яде-бузен залив                                             |
|   94751 | ядерного                                                    |
|   94755 | раз два-три                                                 |
```

---

need: select or remove from the table cyrillic words.

it is necessary to delete the rows in which `ONE Cyrillic word WITHOUT` digit, without special chars, without chars of punctuation.

Condition for removal: '^[а-я]+[а-я]$+'

```
select * from bpsw where badpsw regexp '^[a-z]+[a-z]$+';
```

With English words there are no problems, but with the Cyrillic alphabet I will not understand HOW it make.

I think that it is necessary to specify a collate?

**UPD:** [mysql regex utf-8 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774618/mysql-regex-utf-8-characters) ?

can here i need to look at the meanings of the **Cyrillic symbols in the *byte representation***?

Comment: Give a sample character from words you want to delete.

Comment: Or Give a clear list Example you want to delete.

Comment: @reds,, https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82 all in lowercase а б в г д е ж з и й к л м н о п р с т у ф ч ....

Comment: All of that characters are to be deleted?

Comment: @reds "to delete the rows in which ONE Cyrillic word WITHOUT digit, without special chars, without chars of punctuation." can I do without byte comparison?

Comment: Like what? can you show it here? some example word? any?

Comment: You mean all of this are to be deleted? `94950 | яростных                                             
    1599 | ярь-медянка
   1600 | ястреб-перепелятник
  1601 | ястреб-тетеревятник
  94999 | яфетический 
 1603 | яхт-клуб  
  1604 | яхт-клуба   
...
|    1938 | яванский желоб
|    1939 | яванское море 
|   94690 | еще какое-то слово
|    1940 | яде-бузен залив
|   94751 | ядерного
|   94755 | раз два-три

Comment: chars: а
б
в
г
д
е
ё
ж
з
и
й
к
л
м
н
о
п
р
с
т
у
ф
х
ц
ч
ш
щ
ъ
ы
ь
э
ю
я

Comment: words to delete:  | яростных | яфетический  |  ядерного |

Comment: @reds **UPD:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774618/mysql-regex-utf-8-characters ?

can here i need to look at the meanings of the **Cyrillic symbols in the _byte representation_**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's easy:**

```
select * from bpsw where badpsw regexp '^[абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя]+$';
```

---

https://linux.org.ua/index.php?topic=11272.msg201662#msg201662

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT USER(), CHARSET(USER()), COLLATION(USER());` says virtually nothing.  `USER()` returns a string that is defined by the table that "user" comes from.  It is always utf8.

Perhaps what you want is

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

`REGEXP` works *only* with *bytes*, not non-ascii characters, such as the 2-byte Cyrillic utf8 characters.  (Recent MariaDB versions *can* handle such.)

Instead of `SHOW FULL COLUMNS...`, use `SHOW CREATE TABLE...` -- that will make it more obvious whether the columns are `NOT NULL` or `NULL`.

This can discover Cyrillic strings:

```
WHERE HEX(col) REGEXP '^(..)*D[0-4]'
```

because, in utf8, all Cyrillic characters are 2 bytes, the first of which is HEX D0, D1, D2, D3, or D4.

`SELECT HEX('яростных') REGEXP '^(..)*D[0-4]';` --> `1`

You want to "remove" Cyrillic?  If you want to remove the rows, then a `DELETE` with that `WHERE` will suffice.  If you want to edit the text, that will take application code (unless you have MariaDB and can use [`REGEXP_REPLACE()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/regexp_replace/) ).

Have I addressed all the issues?

**Edit**

To delete the row where col1 contains *just* a single Cyrillic word,

```
 DELETE FROM tbl
     WHERE HEX(col1) REGEXP '^(D[0-4]..)+$';
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. I have already solved this "problem". It was necessary **not just to delete the Cyrillic alphabet**, but `to delete the rows that are WITH ONE Cyrillic word` WITHOUT spaces, WITHOUT hyphens, WITHOUT special chars.

Comment: @root_xPovierennyy - I added the regexp for that.

Comment: %) I instead listed the entire Cyrillic alphabet. regexp '^[абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя]+$'; I'm so more clear. And with encodings (more precisely with bytes) - this is horrible:;))

Comment: @root_xPovierennyy - Yes, my solution is horrible.  But it works.  Your `REGEXP` may incorrectly match other non-english languages.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look at this:

Is this the Record you want to delete?

```
 select  bpswid,badpsw from  Your_Table
 where  badpsw like '%б%' or  badpsw like '%в%'
 or  badpsw like '%г%'
 or   badpsw like '%д%'
 or   badpsw like '%ё%'
 or  badpsw like '%ж%'
 or  badpsw like '%з%'
 or  badpsw like '%и%'
 or  badpsw like '%й%'
 or  badpsw like '%к%'
 or  badpsw like '%л%'
 or  badpsw like '%м%'
 or  badpsw like '%н%'
 or  badpsw like '%п%'
 or  badpsw like '%т%'
 or  badpsw like '%ф%'
 or  badpsw like '%у%'
 or  badpsw like '%ц%'
 or  badpsw like '%ч%'
 or  badpsw like '%ш%'
 or  badpsw like '%щ%'
 or  badpsw like '%ъ%'
 or  badpsw like '%ы%'
 or  badpsw like '%ь%'
 or  badpsw like '%э%'
 or  badpsw like '%ю%'
 or  badpsw like '%я%'
 or  badpsw like '%с%'
 or  badpsw like '%р%'
 or  badpsw like '%х%'
 or  badpsw like '%е%'
or  badpsw like '%о%'
```

Result:

```
94950   яростных
1599    ярь-медянка
1600    ястреб-перепелятник
1601    ястреб-тетеревятник
94999   яфетический
1603    яхт-клуб
1604    яхт-клуба
1938    яванский желоб
1939    яванское море
94690   еще какое-то слово
1940    яде-бузен залив
94751   ядерного
94755   раз два-три
```

if not then just remove the other in like condition. then proceed deletion of record.

Comment: :( no. I did not even check it. Your example will delete all words. **Words to select  are: `яростных яфетический ядерного`** Table `bpsw`consist about 1000000 words.

Comment: what do you mean remove? it removed but the rows still present?

Comment: I did not even check it

Comment: Sorry i don't even catch what you mean to be.

Comment: any idea how this word identified as to be deleted? `яростных яфетический ядерного`

Comment: in cyrillic **'^[а-я]+[а-я]$+'**  I ask about mysql query can to delete `яростных яфетический ядерного` from bpsw table.