# SQL Query to include/exclude characters

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a dictionary table '**dictionary**', where column '**word**' contains the list of all English words.

I want to find all words that contain specific alphabet characters only and exclude the rest of the alphabet. I am able to do so (see the example below), but as you can see, it is downright ugly.

**EXAMPLE**

Currently to find all words that contain letters 'a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z', but exlude rest of the alphabet letters I do this:

```
SELECT word 
FROM   dictionary
WHERE  ( 
          word LIKE '%a%' 
          OR word LIKE '%b%' 
          OR word LIKE '%c%' 
          OR word LIKE '%x%' 
          OR word LIKE '%y%' 
          OR word LIKE '%z%' 
       ) AND ( 
             word NOT LIKE '%d%' 
             AND word NOT LIKE '%e%' 
             AND word NOT LIKE '%f%' 
             AND word NOT LIKE '%g%' 
             AND word NOT LIKE '%h%' 
             AND word NOT LIKE '%i%' 
             AND word NOT LIKE '%j%' 
             AND word NOT LIKE '%k%' 
             AND word NOT LIKE '%l%' 
             AND word NOT LIKE '%m%' 
             AND word NOT LIKE '%n%' 
             AND word NOT LIKE '%o%' 
             AND word NOT LIKE '%p%' 
             AND word NOT LIKE '%q%' 
             AND word NOT LIKE '%r%' 
             AND word NOT LIKE '%s%' 
             AND word NOT LIKE '%t%' 
             AND word NOT LIKE '%u%' 
             AND word NOT LIKE '%v%' 
             AND word NOT LIKE '%w%' )
```

Any way to accomplish this task using some form of regex or other optimization?
Any tricks or hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: how you give i/p i.e. a ,b,c,x,y,z ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using `REGEXP`

```
SELECT `word `
FROM `dictionary`
WHERE `word` REGEXP '[abcxyzABCXYZ]'
    AND `word` NOT REGEXP '[defghijklmnopqrstuvwDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW]'
```

Comment: I was happy way too early... this doesn't support UTF8 alphabet characters :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774618/mysql-regex-utf-8-characters - MySQL regular expression library didn't support the UTF8, However you can use the equivalent HEX to support it

Answer (score 2):

This is a better approach.

```
SELECT word 
FROM dictionary
WHERE word REGEXP '.*[abcxyzABCXYZ].*$' 
AND word NOT REGEXP '.*[defghijklmnopqrstuvwDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW].*$';
```

Comment: This is producing SQL errors. I am not sure why, but it won't execute even though I changed 'city' on the third line to 'word'.

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

```
        set @1='a'\\
        set @2 ='b'\\
        set @3 ='c'\\
        set @4 ='x'\\
        set @5 ='y'\\
        set @6 ='z'\\


        set  @find=CONCAT(@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6)\\


        set  @ALl='abcxyzdefghijklmnopqrstuvw'\\ all alphabets here

        set  @ALl=replace(@ALl,@1,'')\\  replace alphabet that you want
        set  @ALl=replace(@ALl,@2,'')\\
        set  @ALl=replace(@ALl,@3,'')\\
        set  @ALl=replace(@ALl,@4,'')\\
        set  @ALl=replace(@ALl,@5,'')\\
        set  @ALl=replace(@ALl,@6,'')\\

        SELECT word 
        FROM dictionary
        WHERE word RLIKE CONCAT('.*[',@find,'].*$')
        AND word NOT RLIKE CONCAT('.*[',@ALl,'].*$');\\
```

[Check Demo  Here](http://rextester.com/NGP17392)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use `REGEXP` for some reason, then this should work too:

```
SELECT word 
  FROM dictionary
 WHERE Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(
            word, 'a', ''),
                  'b', ''),
                  'c', ''),
                  'x', ''),
                  'y', ''),
                  'z', '') = ''
```

I doubt it will be very fast though. Then again, I'm not sure anything will be fast for this requirement =)

Answer (score 0):

The test is simply:

```
    word REGEXP '^[abcxyz]*$'
```

That says that everything from start (`^`) to end (`$`) must be a string of zero or more (`*`) of the characters (`[]`) `abcxyz`.

I did not include both lower and upper case on the presumption that you are using a case-insensitive collation.

There is no need for the `AND .. NOT`.

There is a possible problem:  If you want to allow `notw`, do you want to match `won't`?  That is, what should be done about punctuation?

(There may be other edge cases that are not adequately specified in the Question.)

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE Field not LIKE '%[^a-z0-9 .]%'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.