# select using like only entered characters

Tags: mysql

I would like do a select query using LIKE but MySQL replies with results having different characters, e.g.

```
select name FROM cities WHERE city LIKE "Muni%"
```

Results:

```
Múnic
Munic
Munich
Múnich
```

How do I eliminate results like Múnic and Múnich, so that just the entered characters are being matched?

Comment: You could change the collation to `latin` on the search. Take a look to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647080/accent-insensitive-search-query-in-mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to conduct an Accent Sensitive search in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500826/how-to-conduct-an-accent-sensitive-search-in-mysql)

Comment: COLLATE utf8_bin did it. Thanks. Are there any performance issues when doing this in the query at runtime, especially when have a large cities DB ?