# MySql equality between o and ø

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, full-text-search, collation

I'm having some problems with a query.
I would like to run a query like

```
select *
from products
where MATCH(author) against('jorgen')
```

the problem is that in my DB the actual value is **jørgen** so the query doesn't return anything

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647080/accent-insensitive-search-query-in-mysql talks about Polish and recommends using a qualifier on the test and using `utf8_general_ci`.  That's 3 things that _might_ be different than this question, so I am voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

What `COLLATION` are you using? Most treat `ø` as a distinct letter that comes between `o` and `p`. See mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html . utf8_unicode_520_ci is the only collation (in 5.7 or earlier) that treats the `ø` and `o` as "equal".

The 0900 collations of MySQL 8.0 tend to treat the two letters as equal. See mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html

I suspect the syntax does not let you change the collation during a `FULLTEXT` test, so I think you are stuck with picking a different `COLLATION` and rebuilding the FT index.  And you may want to upgrade to MySQL 8.