# Rails/SQL: Use Æ and AE interchangeably

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

A Rails application I'm currently working on uses the character `Æ` in some database values. How can I create a `SELECT` statement that will treat `Æ` and `AE` as equal?

e.g.: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE lower(name) = 'aether'` should return a row where the value in the `name` column is `Aether` OR `Æther`.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, selects merely return whatever you tell it to. Select doesn't care what is in your database. Please elaborate what you mean when you say "will treat Æ the same as AE"

Comment: I edited the question in an attempt to clarify. I'm not quite sure how to word it properly.

Comment: Not sure if it will work exactly, but this is full of interesting things to try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302813/normalizing-accented-characters-in-mysql-queries

Comment: If I get no other answers this might work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After another lengthy Google session, I finally stumbled upon the answer.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE lower(replace(name,'Æ','Ae')) = 'aether'
```

...appears to give the correct result. You can now cease your downvoting.